# Angular upload/download Rename/delete json file

Tags: json, angular, typescript

am trying to add functions to my existing Angular project.
I need to add features like upload , download , rename or delete json file.
So I need some advice , for the easy way to do that because am new and learning typescript and angular.
Can you please guide me

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I can answer download
There are three steps you need to do

1- Issue the proper request from angular side

```
download(): Observable<HttpResponse<Blob>> {
return this.http.get<HttpResponse<Blob>>(someURL, {
  observe: 'response',
  responseType: 'blob'
}); as any }
```

2- At your backend you need to set the proper headers with response, this snippet of code works with .net4.7 to return csv file contents

```
var contents = new byte[0]; //set your file contents at this line
var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) { Content = new 
ByteArrayContent(contents)};
response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new 
ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
{
   FileName = file.Name
}
response.Content.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content- 
Disposition");
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue ("text/csv");
return response;
```

3- Finally subscribe to the http request at angular side

```
const result 
 = this.service.download()
  .subscribe(res=> {
     let contentDisposition = res.headers.get('content-disposition');
     let filename = contentDisposition.split(';')[1].split('filename') 
         [1].split('=')[1].trim();
     let blob = res.body;
     const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
     const link = document.createElement('a');
     link.href = url;
     link.download = fileName;
     document.body.appendChild(link);
     link.click();
     window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
     link.parentNode.removeChild(link);
   });
```

Comment: Thank you sir but it looks little bit complicated , in fact my project is a scrabble game where I have to upload new dictionaries through HTML and where I can modify the name of the Dictionary,  Delete it or download a copy of the JSON on my computer. Can I do something more simple than that? I dont have to modify JSON content just the name or download it like it is? Thank you again

Comment: I thought by download to download a file,  apparently you just need to send and get data from server which is indeed more simpler that that

Comment: Do you hqve qny example for a good approach to the problem? Am asking from experienced people like you to not do beginners mistakes

Comment: https://www.telerik.com/blogs/angular-basics-how-to-use-httpclient?kw=&cpn=13466528126&gclsrc=aw.ds&&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=kendo-ui-angular-trial-search-bms-NA&ad_group=Angular+DSA&utm_term=DYNAMIC+SEARCH+ADS&ad_copy=&ad_type=search_DSA&ad_size=DSA3_blazor-dsa_D1-build-professional-ui-with-a-popular-collection-of-100+-native-angular-components&ad_placement=&gclid=Cj0KCQiA-K2MBhC-ARIsAMtLKRvNS4K0pJFNwYW_JoGh_AnvBhimC8atwHDCaBht2gtjYkgYq2wPe0QaAlkdEALw_wcB